# Geo DNS for webmail server

Tags: dns-hosting

I have a webmail server in Sunnyvale, California. I have branch offices in Romania, Spain, China, and Vietnam. They all complaint slowness in accesing webmail in CA. In each office I have Juniper webvpn installed. Is it possible to have some kind of dns pointing to the Juniper webvpn locally so that the access of webmail would be faster? Some kind of Geo DNS type of configuration?

Comment: I don't understand your question; how would accessing the webvpn be faster?  Are you proposing accessing the web mail across the vpn rather than across the internet?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one point of entry (ie the sunnyvale office), then there's only a few things i can think of.

1.) If this is an exchange server, i would reccomend setting up RPC over HTTP with an cached mode enabled in outlook.  Presuming you can use outlook of course and that you have the right outlook client.

2.) If you have  VPN and you have some cash, get a WAN optimazation device (riverbed is my favorite).  This will help out quite a bit with peformance by caching a lot of the requests locally.

3.) you could use an akami to cache some stuff on your webmail site, but it probably won't help much with the stuff that hurting peformance.

4.) also, if you think it's just that DNS is taking forever to respond (i don't think thats your problem) cloudleverage is a vendor that offers global DNS, caching, etc.